Expressing $\frac{x^3-1}{x^2-2}$ as the sum of a polynomial and another rational function
The problem:
Express the given rational function as the sum of a polynomial and another rational function whose numerator is either zero or has smaller degree than the denominator.
$$\frac{x^3-1}{x^2-2}$$
The answer:
$$x+\frac{2x-1}{x^2-2}$$
What I have tried:
I reversed the answer back to how it originally looked to try to find out what the method one was expected to use.
$$x+\frac{2x-1}{x^2-2} = \frac{x(x^2-2)+2x-1}{x^2-2} = \frac{x^3-2x+2x-1}{x^2-2} = \frac{x^3-1}{x^2-2}$$
If I look at this backwards one is expected to subtract $2x$ and add $2x$ in the numerator to rewrite the original function in the way the problem asks one to write it. Why is that? Is an algrebraic formula that I do not know about being utilized? I would like to solve this type of problem without the aid of knowing the answer already.

Do you know the division algorithm for polynomials in one variable over the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$? In essence what the exercise then boils down to is to divide the numerator by the denominator and $2x - 1$ is the residue of that algorithm. EDIT: Another name for this is "polynomial long division".

I am simply to do polynomial long division?

Yes, polynomial long division

Yes, indeed! :) Because this way you can write $x^3 - 1 = q(x^2-2) + r$ for some quotient polynomial $q$ (in your case $x$) and a residue polynomial $r$ (in your case $2x - 1$).

Use division method or Detached coefficient method

Comments should not be used for giving answers per site policy. This is NOT a discussion forum.

(see also https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

We can convert the original to the form you want by using polynomial long division. It will be hard to write the full steps using MathJax but I can provide a run down.
We begin by writing it as you would a normal long division problem:
$$x^2-2 | x^3-0x^2+0x-1$$
We divide the leading coefficients in the numerator and the divisor:
$$\frac{x^3}{x^2}=x$$
This is the first part of the quotient. Now just as we would with long division, we continue by multiplying and subtracting.
$$x(x^2-2)=x^3-2x$$
$$(x^3-0x^2+0x-1)-(x^3-2x)=2x-1$$
Now we've found the remainder, and we can add it to the quotient we found previously.
Therefore, $$\frac{x^3-1}{x^2-2}=x+\frac{2x-1}{x^2-2}$$
If this wasn't clear, try following along with the steps written out here.

Notice that there is an $x^2-2$ in the denominator. If you add and subtract $2x$ you can factor that out form $x^3-2x$ and keep everything else the same.

Note that for $x = \pm \sqrt{2}$, the function is undefined since the denominator goes to $0$. So let's assume $\color\red{x \ne \pm \sqrt{2}}$ for now for the simplifications shown below.
The formulas I use are $\color\orange{\mathbf{x^2-a^2 = (x+a)(x-a)}}$ and $\color\orange{\mathbf{x^3-a^3 = (x-a)(x^2+ax+a^2)}}$
$$
\begin{align}
p(x) & = \frac{x^3-1}{x^2-2} \\
&= \frac{x^3 \color\red{- (\sqrt{2})^3 + (\sqrt{2})^3} -1}{x^2-(\sqrt{2})^2} \\
&= \frac{x^3-(\sqrt{2})^3}{x^2-(\sqrt{2})^2} + \frac{(\sqrt{2})^3-1}{x^2-2} \\
&= \frac{\color\red{(x-\sqrt{2})}(x^2+x\sqrt{2}+2)}{\color\red{(x-\sqrt{2})}(x+\sqrt{2})} + \frac{(\sqrt{2})^3-1}{x^2-2} \\
&= \frac{x\color\red{(x+\sqrt{2})}+2}{\color\red{x+\sqrt{2}}} + \frac{(\sqrt{2})^3-1}{x^2-2}\\
&= x + \frac{2}{x+\sqrt{2}} + \frac{(\sqrt{2})^3-1}{x^2-2} \\
&= x + \frac{2(x-\sqrt{2})+(\sqrt{2})^3-1}{x^2-2}\\
&= x + \frac{2x-1\color\red{-(\sqrt{2})^3+(\sqrt{2})^3}}{x^2-2}\\
&= x + \frac{2x-1}{x^2-2}\\
\end{align}
$$
Notice that we are allowed to cancel the red terms because of our assumption $\color\red{x \ne \pm \sqrt{2}}$

Long division method is just simpler here, but I wanted to show an alternative, if it helps
